# Get final value of a recursive async directory search with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous

The code below prints [ ] in the console, filenames Array is actually being changed, but the print occurs before it happens. How to get the final valeu of filenames array, after all changes occurs?

```
function search(directoryPath, searchString, filenames) {

    fs.readdir(directoryPath, { withFileTypes: true }, function (err, files) {

        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        }

        files.forEach(function (file) {

            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if (file.name === searchString) {
                    
                    filenames.push(file.name)
                }
                search(directoryPath + "/" + file.name, searchString, filenames);
            }
        });
    });
}

const filenames = []
search(directoryPath, "1048594132", filenames);
console.log(filenames);
```

Comment: Do you only want to find directories that match `searchString` or [regular] files, too?

Comment: only directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to only use synchronous functions. You can do this by replacing the asynchronous `fs.readdir()` with the synchronous [fs.readdirSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options).